# FATAL: OneSignal AppId format is invalid ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am Developing an ionic App where i am implementing OneSignal Push Notifications. I have previously done it but now i am getting this error:

**FATAL: OneSignal AppId format is invalid**

i have checked infinite no. of times but my AppID is correct. I have removed & added the plugin & platforms multiple times but still no good. I am getting this error in Xcode when i start the app. Here is my plugin list:

```
com.googlemaps.ios 2.5.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.8.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 5.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 3.0.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.1.2-beta-20171122-2100 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.15 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.4-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.1.2 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.2.4 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

**i am using ionic version: 3.18.0**

Please Help as i am stuck badly on it....

Comment: I have same issue :(